# How is Citymapper not breaking the Google Maps Terms of Service?

Tags: terms-of-service

Having read the [Google Maps Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4), I don't understand how [Citymapper](https://citymapper.com/) is not breaking section 10.4.c: "Restrictions on Unfair Exploitation of the Service and Content."

Surely they must be using the Google Maps API as part of their service, and Citymapper is an alternative to using Google Maps.

Comment: On which grounds do you suspect it of violating the terms of service?

Comment: @phoog Cobbles said "Surely they must be using the Google Maps API as part of their service, and Citymapper is an alternative to using Google Maps." I think it's clear that Cobbles thinks that it is on those grounds that it violates the terms of services.

Comment: @Dawn thanks, I overlooked the significance of that last bit.  Cobbles: I suppose Citymapper is not a substitute service.  It doesn't calculate directions between cities, for example, and there are other features of Google maps that it does not have.  Also, its transportation directions offer more information than those of Google maps.

Comment: @phoog I suppose you could be right, thanks. It still seems very close to a substitute though

Comment: @Cobbles yes, there's definitely lots of room for subjectivity here.  I don't suppose Google has publicly expressed any opinion on what they consider to be a "substitute service."  It's also possible that Citymapper has negotiated with Google because of this concern, and if so they may be operating under different terms of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TOS for Citymapper](https://global-api.citymapper.com/resourceproxy/tos.html) states that

> We use third parties, such as Transport for London, Metropolitan
>   Transport Authority and other transport agencies, Apple, **Google**,
>   OpenStreetMap, Foursquare, Yelp to provide data on which the transport
>   information and recommendations in the app are based. We and our
>   partners try to make sure that the data is correct and up-to-date...

So they must have agreements with those companies and government entities to access the data.